# Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab

i read a csv file with textscan and when i want write in a file i receive this error : Error using horzcat. Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

if i change the first format in textscan (i mean %S) to %f the error vanishes.
 the error occurs when matlab want to make [datatest{1} probability]

probability is 1000*1 double
datatest{1} is 1000*1 cell

```
datatest=textscan(FileID,'%s %*f %f %f %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f',1000,'headerlines',1,'delimiter',',');

csvwrite('output.csv',[datatest{1} probability]);
```

Comment: You need to check the dimensions of the matrices before you concatenate them.

Comment: what if you try [datatest{1} num2cell(probability)] ?

Comment: if i use num2cell another error occurs

Comment: both dimensions are 1000*1

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of your data so we can test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `datatest{1}` contains 1000 cells which each contains a string (may be or may be not the same length).

In your statement `[datatest{1} probability]` you are trying to concatenate `cells` (containing strings) with `double` numeric type, this does not work. The concatenation operator needs to operate on data of similar type.

Now even if you were to create a cell array which would contain all your desired columns `myCellArray={datatest{1} probability}`, this would not help you because the output of that cannot be passed on the function `csvwrite`.

`csvwrite`, or the better sister `dlmwrite`, do not accept cell arrays. You would have to convert the cell values into numeric values. Unfortunately, you want to write strings and numeric values, so your only way is to use low level functions like [`fprintf`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)

In your case, to write the file you were expecting, you can use the following code.

```
col1 = datatest{1} ;                %// extract the column of interest for easier indexing later on
fidw = fopen('output.csv','w') ;    %// get a handle on a file to write (necessary with "fprintf")
for iline = 1:numel(probability)    %// loop on each line
    fprintf( fidw , '%s, %f\n' , col1{iline} , probability(iline) ) ; %// write the line
end
fclose(fidw) ;                      %// close the file - IMPORTANT - (necessary with "fprintf")
```